# Web Server that can stream .MKV videos

Tags: windows-10, webserver, video-streaming

I'm on Windows 10 Pro and would like to play movies that are on it from a remote device through HTTP with a simple directory listing of my whole movies folder.

I've tried Windows' IIS but there is no MIME type that correctly accommodates .mkv with multiple audio/subtitle tracks.

Any ideas?

Comment: [How to play MKV file in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018119/how-to-play-mkv-file-in-browser)

Comment: Hello @Seth as explained in the original question, the browser doesn't know how to handle multiple audio/subtitle tracks within the MKV file.

Comment: For the MIME types of MKV see the above question. If your browser doesn't support subtitle selection use a different browser. If no browser supports it find a different setup. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222410/do-browsers-like-chrome-and-firefox-support-displaying-srt-subtitles-in-movies) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video).

Comment: @Seth what about the audio track?

Comment: What about it? A mkv is a container. If you player doesn't properly support it use a different one. For HTML there [might be APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks).